# Api Restful laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-auth

Olá,

estou tentando criar uma api no laravel 5.2

o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte:

1 - continuar usando o sistema de auth padrão para usuário web.

2 - criar uma api para usuários de um aplicativo.

estou usando o método: auth:api, porém com este método eu sou obrigado a saber o token do usuário e o que eu queria era é o seguinte na api o usuário digitar o user e password dai com isto me retornaria o token e ele poderia acessar as paginas deles ou cadastros etc...

minha route.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return Auth::guard('api')->user();
    });
});
```

obrigado

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o jwt? Veja aqui: https://github.com/code-sample/laravel-jwt-auth

Comment: @Evert muito obrigado pelo link, aparentemente esta tudo ok. Obrigadooo

Answer (score 2):

Para a obtenção do token inicial, você precisa criar uma rota fora do grupo que usa middleware `auth.api`

uma simples rota como `api/authenticate` que receba os dados do usuário e retorne o token, caso o login seja feito com sucesso

Answer (score -1):

A solução para o meu problema foi o link: 
[laravel-jwt-auth](https://github.com/code-sample/laravel-jwt-auth)

Comment: Poderia descrever a solução ou copiar parte da explicação do link para a sua resposta?